# how to know if video driver is installed?

Tags: linux, debian, drivers

I've Debian Squeeze installed on my desktop, how do I know if my video card (its driver) is properly installed?

This is part of the lspci command output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
```

and this is part of lshw command output:

```
*-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:30 memory:d0200000-d02fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff(prefetchable) ioport:2168(size=8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo lsmod` and review the output. You will probably be using the i915 driver.

Comment: The output does contain video-14605-1-i915, it means that the driver is properly installed and in use?

Comment: If you can see on the monitor, I would say yes. Are you getting the resolution options you desire? If so, then definitely, yes.